# How can I use JavaScript to lay out ("draw") dynamically generated <DIV>s in different screen positions and sizes in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have data from an API which will generate a set of blocks, each with an x, a y, a height, and a width.  They can interlock in a variety of ways, none of which is predictable. What is the best way to approach laying these out, writing out the data in my `render` method in React?

I realize that I can probably write each `<DIV>`'s `style` inline inside my React `render` code, but I'd like to find a more elegant way and at the moment my brain is coming up empty.  I was looking into doing this with CSS Sprites (which came up after some googling), but as I've been tasked with doing this quickly, and since I know nothing about CSS Sprites, I would like to find a simpler way.

I'd appreciate any clues or insights.  (What's ironic is that I come, long ago, from an ActionScript background, where this was all obvious, but the disconnect between the JS and CSS in the JS world makes it a bit trickier for me).

Comment: You were on the right track with thinking about inline styles. The current best practice for something like this is one of the many flavors of CSS-in-JS, where you parse your fetched data and use it to dynamically construct style rules for elements.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo.  Thanks --  you mean packages like emotion (https://www.npmjs.com/package/emotion) ?

Comment: Yes. I like styled-components but emotion is cool too...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know React, but can't you just use css and media queries?
https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries

Comment: It's more about drawing elements on the screen dynamically.  The CSS can't be pre-written  -- I'm familiar with media queries but I don't think that would help much here.